# How do I tell a Makefile which dependencies are satisfied by which target

Tags: makefile, dependencies, rules

I am creating a Makefile to drive the generation of EPUB3 eBooks from an archive of XML documents. I'm having trouble understanding how to tell *make* that a specific filename or directory dependency can be satisfied by another target.

Grossly simplified:

```
dir:
       mkdir testing

files: testing
       echo foobar >testing/blort
```

This of course produces:

```
% make files
make: *** No rule to make target `testing', needed by `files'. Stop.
```

The *files* target requires the existence of the *testing* directory for it to work. How do I tell *make* that the directory can be created by performing the target *dir*?

(In this simplified case the answer is to make the *testing* dependency the target *dir* instead of the hardwired directory name.)

But in reality, these recipes are quite long and do a huge amount of other stuff (eg extracting metadata from XML documents) and use variable rather than hardcoded filenames. **Is there a way to tell *make* that one specific filename or directory dependency can be satisfied by performing another target?** Or will I need to break the whole thing down into atomics (basically one shell command per target)?

In effect, is there a way to tell *make* that target *x* creates file *y*? Is this something pattern rules can so (a part of *make* that I have never used)?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to tell make that target x creates file y

You need to adjust your terminology.  A *target* is the thing that gets created.  A *recipe* (shell commands or whatever) creates the target.  A *prerequisite* is a file or target that is used to create a target, such that the target needs to be updated (using the recipe) if the prerequisite is newer than the target.  Make will first consider each prerequisite as if it were a target, recursively, and try to ensure it is up to date.

Then you write your rule:

```
<target> : [<prerequisite> [<prerequisite> ...]]
        <recipe>
```

So, if you want to write a rule that creates file *y* from prerequisite *x* you'd write:

```
y : x
        <recipe>
```

In your example above you are relying on a prerequisite `testing`, but you have no rule that builds the target `testing`.  You have a rule that builds target `dir`, which is not helpful.  Rewrite the rule:

```
testing:
        mkdir testing
```

(although this isn't really a good way to deal with directories).

Comment: Thank you very much for the succinct explanation, much clearer than the docs. It was abundantly unclear that a target has to be a filename: I was treating them as labels. I only have to create a couple of directories, but if there is a better way to do it I'd be interested.

Comment: A target doesn't _HAVE_ to be a filename.  But if it's not a filename, then it can't ever be up to date, so these are typically only used to run other commands, for example `clean` or `install`.  Also I'm not sure what docs you're reading but the first introductory section of the GNU make manual is pretty clear on this, IMO: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html

Comment: Regarding creating directories: the best way to do it depends on why you're doing it.  The simplest way is to just add the `mkdir` into the recipes that need them, especially if there are only a few.  The problem with using directories as prerequisites is that `make` is completely dependent on modification timestamps on the files it looks at.  The modification time of a directory is updated whenever a file is added, deleted, or renamed in that directory.  This means that any time you create a new file, all target depending on the directory will be considered out of date.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dependency to a folder in a makefile you should use  [order-only-prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) instead of normal prerequisites.
With order-only-prerequisites the folder will only be created once, make will not care about the time stamp.

Example:

```
all: testing/file1.txt testing/file2.txt

testing:
    @mkdir -p testing

testing/file1.txt: | testing
    <generate testing/file1.txt>

testing/file2.txt: | testing
    <generate testing/file2.txt>
```

It think you always should use make-targets to create folders, especially if two or more targets are depending on the folder.